# Rackunit equality-checking for structs

Tags: testing, scheme, racket

I'm trying to test out a tokenizer/parser combo for a compiler in racket, and I have a function `parse-string`, contract-typed to something like `(-> string? ast:IntExp)` (I know, I should probably rename my structs, but I was experimenting with typed racket for a little while there.
Anyway, I have a test bank written up with stuff like 
`(check-equal? (parse-string "4") (ast:IntExp 4))`, and all of the tests fail, even though upon manual inspection, they look like they ought to pass. All of my structs are defined with `define-struct/contract`, and all of them are marked `#:transparent`.
What's going wrong here?

Okay, sorry for not including enough source to be helpful:

Here's the struct definition for `IntExp`: 
`(define-struct/contract (IntExp Exp) ([val integer?]) #:transparent)`
Here's the test: `(check-equal? (parse-string "4") (ast:IntExp 4))`
Here's the complaint rackunit gives back:

`--------------------
FAILURE
actual:     #(struct:IntExp ... 4)
expected:   #(struct:IntExp ... 4)
name:       check-equal?
location:   (#<path:/Users/clem/dev/tiger/parser-lexer-tests.rkt> 8 0 139 48)
expression: (check-equal? (parse-string "4") (ast:IntExp 4))`

And, just in case, here's the dependencies I'm `require`ing:

`(require "lexer.rkt"
         "parser.rkt"
         parser-tools/lex
         (prefix-in ast: "ast.rkt")
         rackunit)`

The actual parser code is kind of large, and I have a hunch that it's not the source of the problem, because all of my tests are failing in this way (the results, upon inspection, seem correct). My bet is that I'm doing something very silly in rackunit.

Comment: So you have a procedure `parse-string` that evaluates to a struct and another version of that struct initialized with the same values `parse-string` would use and you get `#f` for `check-equal?` between them? I think you need to supply more code if you need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racket was using reference-equality because the structs in question inherited from an opaque struct-type. As per [the docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define-struct.html), either make the opaque parent structs transparent, or add an
`equal?-recur` method which compares the underlying structure.